# Написать метод предназначенный для сохранения книг в базу данных

Tags: java

При сохранении каждой книге даётся уникальный номер (id).
Id это целое число. Первая в базе книга получает значение id = 1,
вторая id = 2 и так далее (автоинкремент - для каждой следующей книги
значение id просто увеличивается на единицу). Id присваивается в момент
сохранения книги в базу данных и больше никогда не меняется.

```
private static final Long ID = 0L;

public Long save(Book book) {
    book.setId(ID + 1);
    database.add(book);
    return book.getId();
}
```

пробовал так, не выходит

Comment: `пробовал так, не выходит` предлагаете угадать, что не работает у вас?

Comment: с такой реализацией метода всем книгам присваивается ID = 1, а мне надо чтобы было 1, 2, 3, ... т.д.

Comment: При вставке новой записи в бд, можно использовать id bd это будет уникальное значение. При создание таблицы просто укажите AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: book.setId(ID + 1); измените на book.setId(++ID);

Comment: для SQL еще маленький), Дмитрий спс --- работает, но я че та не могу понять, как лайкнуть?